# Which resources in Azure can I change the names of and it will not break anything?

Tags: azure

We have misnamed some of our resources in Azure and we want reorganize the structure. We want to rename some resources, if this does not break anything.

An example is that we have a subscription that is for both prod and nonprod and is so named, and we want to create a non-prod subscription and then **rename** the current subscription so it is clear one is prod and one is non-prod.

Can we change the name of the current subscription? Is there a list of resources that can or cannot be renamed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot rename existing resources. If you're trying to standardize existing resources, it becomes impossible to adopt a universal naming convention. All you can do is move an existing resource group to a new resource group OR create a new resource with the same name and settings.

You can rename the subscription but certainly, it will not have an impact

Comment: That part of your answer is wrong "You can rename the subscription but certainly, it will have an impact". See my answer. Sub name is only for display purposes.

Comment: Have you meant “ create a new resource with the **NEW** name and same settings.”?

Answer (score 2):

You can rename a subscription. That is only a display name and has no impact. Resources or resource groups cannot be renamed in general.

As written before, you can at best move resources into a new resource group.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. This is good news really, as I want to rename the subscription but I don't want to really rename the resources so much as recreate them with the new name. I *think* it would be easiest to do this by just saving the resource as a template in a json file, then change the name (and anything else I needed to), and recreate the resource, then delete the old resource. You would have to be careful about resource hierarchy, probably best to start at the top and work your way down.

Comment: would be a good chance to templatize your entire environment as infrastructure-as-code ;) Either in ARM templates or Terraform

Comment: Was just discussing this with our admin. Totally want to move in this direction. Is Terraform a 3rd party product. I am going to dive deeper into ARM templates in order to templatize everything we can.

Comment: yes, Terraform is 3rd party (open source). If you only plan to deploy Azure resources, going from ARM is probably the better move as it's native Azure

Comment: I just learned that you can rename an Application Insights resource via the portal.